# Trying to use MockMvc together with Wiremock

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wiremock

I'm trying to make a mockMvc call run together with wiremock. But the mockMvc call below in the code keeps throwing 404 instead of the expected 200 HTTP status code.

I know that wiremock is running .. I can do http://localhost:8070/lala through browser when wiremock is running.

Can someone please advise ?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApp.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyControllerTest { 


    @Inject
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    @ClassRule
    public static final WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(8070);

    @Rule
    public WireMockClassRule instanceRule = wireMockRule;

    public ResponseDefinitionBuilder responseBuilder(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        return aResponse()
                .withStatus(httpStatus.value());
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() throws Exception {
        stubFor(WireMock
                .request(HttpMethod.GET.name(), urlPathMatching("/lala"))
                .willReturn(responseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)));

        Thread.sleep(1000000);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.request(HttpMethod.GET, "/lala")) .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the code in the post to show the complete test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `@SpringBootTest` runs with a mocked environment and hence doesn't have a port assigned, [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

> **Another useful approach is to not start the server at all but to test only the layer below that, where Spring handles the incoming HTTP request and hands it off to your controller. That way, almost of the full stack is used, and your code will be called in exactly the same way as if it were processing a real HTTP request but without the cost of starting the server**

so `MockMvc` does not pointing to wiremockport (8070) which exactly says `404`. If you want do test with wiremock you can use `HttpClients` like [here](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock)

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8070/lala");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Or you can just use spring boot web integration test feature by mocking any service calling from controller like shown [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)